# JQuery problems sending objects (OPTIONS request instead of POST)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, web-services

I have a Web Service that recive an JSON Object Prueba

```
public class Prueba
{
  public string valor1 { get; set; }
  public string valor2 { get; set; }
}

public JsonResult Pruebas(Prueba item)
{
   string metodo = Request.HttpMethod;
   return Json("error", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And I want to call to the web service with JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://localhost:24780/Api/Pruebas',
            data:'{"valor1":"a","valor2":"b"}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                console.debug(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.debug(data);
            }
        });
```

The problem is that Request.method takes the value OPTION instead of POST. Also the object value is null.

I have tested the web service with SOAP UI without problems but I can't find why it don't work with JQuery.

Comment: You have a `POST` AJAX call, does your web-service method support `POST` or `GET`?

Comment: Also, please get rid of the MVC tag, I don't think it belongs on this question.

Comment: @Vimal The web-service support POST. I added the TAG now because I found that without the entry contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' in ajax the Request.method takes the right value. But it still don't works because it doesn't recognize the JSON object.

Comment: You might find the solution here: [Cross-domain POST AJAX requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually it doesn't work still I'd published the web service in a server.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to send a string instead of an object. This is why on server error you retrieve anything but not an object. Try to replace this:

```
data:'{"valor1":"a","valor2":"b"}',
```

to this:

```
data:{"valor1":"a","valor2":"b"},
```

Answer (score 0):

you are making your  object as string by using single quotes around it.
That is the reason you are not getting value of object